# Получаю ошибку при get запросе к api

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

Осуществляю get-запрос через postman, но получаю в ответ:

```
GET /api/v1/skins/?steamid=STEAMid
{
    "detail": "Учетные данные не были предоставлены."
}
```

Код класса апи:

```
class SkinsView(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    id64 = int(request.data.get("steamid"))
    skins = Skin.objects.filter(user=ProfileSteam.objects.get(id64=id64).user)
    serializer = SkinSerializer(skins, many=True)

    return Response({'skins':serializer.data})
```

Авторизаци класс апи не требует, поэтому не могу понять где ошибка.